# Error while using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm using pandas package in anaconda IDE..... When I'm trying to load a dataframe I'm getting PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!.... Please help me solving this.

This is the block of code I'm trying to execute:

```
total_sales_yearly = vg_sales.groupby(['Year']).sum()
drop=["Rank","Platform","Genre","Publisher"]
data=total_sales_yearly.drop(total_sales_yearly[drop],axis=1)
cols=["JP_Sales","Other_Sales"]
time=pd.DataFrame(range(1980,2019,1))
print(time)
```

This is the Error I'm getting:

```
PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `dict` with column name:

```
time=pd.DataFrame({'col':range(1980,2019,1)})
print(time)
     col
0   1980
1   1981
2   1982
3   1983
4   1984
5   1985
6   1986
7   1987
8   1988
9   1989
10  1990
11  1991
```

Or convert to `list` - get default column name `0`:

```
time=pd.DataFrame(list(range(1980,2019,1)))
print(time)
       0
0   1980
1   1981
2   1982
3   1983
4   1984
5   1985
6   1986
7   1987
8   1988
9   1989
10  1990
11  1991
12  1992
13  1993
14  1994
15  1995
```

And if need row add `[]`:

```
time=pd.DataFrame([range(1980,2019,1)])
print(time)
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   ...     29  \
0  1980  1981  1982  1983  1984  1985  1986  1987  1988  1989  ...   2009   

     30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38  
0  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  

[1 rows x 39 columns]
```

EDIT:

Also is possible simplify :

```
data=total_sales_yearly.drop(total_sales_yearly[drop],axis=1)
```

to:

```
data=total_sales_yearly.drop(drop,axis=1)
```